# Keyboard key press listener

Tags: arduino-leonardo, keyboard

Is there a way to make a listener for a key press to begin a loop?

Example:  I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key on my keyboard and the programmed loop begins running.

Essentially creating a keyboard hotkey.

Comment: Please edit your question so that it meets the quality standards set out in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and no.

Only the Arduino and its IDE, no.

The way I found is to use Processing to wait until it detects a hotkey, then send a serial message to your Arduino. If you tune in the right COM port, this should work.